# Arcpy Update Cursor IO error "c" does not exist

Tags: python, arcpy

I wrote this quick script to find the min. depth in bathymetry polygons based on the contour lines bounding them:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import arcpy.da

# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Working"

area ="conta"
line = "contl"

for i in area:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(line, 'intersect', area)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(line, 'subset_selection',
            """[DEPTH] in (SELECT min( [DEPTH] ) FROM contl)""")

    cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(i)
    for row in cursor:
        row.setValue('DEPTHMIN',row.getValue(line['DEPTH']))
        cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor
```

The selections work just fine, but when I try to run my instance through a update cursor I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 30, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1199, in UpdateCursor
    return gp.updateCursor(dataset, where_clause, spatial_reference, fields, sort_fields)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 364, in updateCursor
    self._gp.UpdateCursor(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
IOError: "c" does not exist
```

I'm not sure what this `"c"` that Python is looking for is.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies here: `arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Working"`

What you need to do is either:

`arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Working"`

or

`arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Working"`

Edit:
Your first clue is it's an IO error. It is having trouble outputting (the "O" part) to your environment path. This can occur due to a number of reasons, but in your case it is the path, which contains the escape character `\` that botches the whole thing. So you need to either use the forward slash `/` or put an `r` in front of the string to indicate to the interpreter that it should be handled as a `raw` string.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is here:

```
area ="conta"
for i in area:
```

`area` is a string, so when you use `for i in ...` with string object you iterate over "characters" in string. First step of your iteration is a letter "c" and it doesn't exist as a data source.

Path issue has to be fixed too.